# In Facebook Groups, is there any way to delete multiple photos?

Tags: facebook-groups, facebook-photos

I am an admin on a couple of Facebook group pages. Deleting the photos on these groups is a fulltime and tedious job. Is there a way to delete multiple photos at once? Is there a way to change the sequence of them so the oldest photos show first, as opposed to the newest? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue